# Expression Engine Channel/Category Setup

Tags: url, expressionengine, categories

I'm trying to work out EE, and how best to build my site structure. Inspiration from saveur.com - the recipes menu.

Mini sitemap for this section as follows.

```
Homepage

    Recipes - landing page

        Course - post category  - landing page
            Breakfast - post subcategories  - landing page
            Brunch
            Lunch
            Mains
            Deserts
            Appetizers

        Ingredients
            Eggs
            Chicken
            Avacado
            Fish
```

Can anyone explain to me the basic idea of Expression Engine channel/categories/entries, because I think I'm missing something. Take the following URL

```
/recipes/course/breakfast/scrambled-eggs
```

Recipes is the channel, with a Channel URL saved. 404 page.

Course and breakfast are both categories - landing pages that will never have content published to, but will list an index of content from their child pages. Both segments return 404. Even when Category URL's are saved

The only segment that is active is the entry itself - scrambled-eggs.

If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd be very greatful.

Comment: If you are not getting the response you were hoping for here consider posting on http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd say: Create a Recipes **Channel Fields Group** with ingredients
   as a **grid**.
2. Create the Course **Category Group** and add: Breakfast Brunch Lunch
   Mains Deserts Appetizers to it.
3. Create a Rescipes **Channel** and assign to it both the Recipes
   **Channel Fields** Group and the Courses **Category Group**.
4. Create a Recipes Template group and you simply use the code below to list all your Menu items

   {exp:channel:entries channe="Recipes"}
              {title}
              {ingredients}
                 {ingredient}
              {/ingredients}
           {/exp:channel:entries}

> You can also use this link structure (/Recipes/Breakfast/) and EE will
>   dynamically return all the entries from the breakfast course